# Process hangs when trying to read bytes from buffer to int. Wkhtmltopdf

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wkhtmltopdf

My method creates PDF out of HTML content with `Wkhtmltopdf` program with `Process`. I can't find a reason why it hangs. When there is a big string with HTML, i suppose it hangs when there are 30 pages or more. But everything works fine if there are less pages. Wkhtmltopdf.exe process i can see at the `Task Manager`, it does not exit forever. When i stop my MVC project with `hanged` Wkhtmltopdf, `it creates normally` PDF like it would wait for something.. Manually, of course, Wkhtmltopdf creates everything without any problem.
This is not duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58448346/streamwriter-get-stuck-on-write-process-standardinput-wkhtmltopdf). Here i have issues when trying to read **bytes** into int.

```
public IActionResult createPdf()
{
    string html = "content";

    Process p;
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

    psi.FileName = "...\\wkhtmltopdf.exe";
    psi.WorkingDirectory = "...\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin";

    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
    psi.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    psi.Arguments = "-O landscape --footer-left qwe --footer-center [page]/[topage] --footer-right --footer-font-size 9 --no-stop-slow-scripts --zoom 0.8 --dpi 300 - - ";

    p = Process.Start(psi);

    byte[] pdf = null;

    try
    {
        // Get PDF as bytes without temp files
        using(StreamWriter stdin = new StreamWriter(p.StandardInput.BaseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
              stdin.AutoFlush = true;
              stdin.Write(html);
         }

         byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
         using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
         {
              while(true)
              {
                   // HANGS HERE!!!
                   int read = p.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); 

                   if(read <= 0)
                   {
                       break;
                   }       
                   ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
              }
              pdf = ms.ToArray();
          }      
    }
    ...


}
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58448346/streamwriter-get-stuck-on-write-process-standardinput-wkhtmltopdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StreamWriter get stuck on Write. Process.StandardInput, Wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58448346/streamwriter-get-stuck-on-write-process-standardinput-wkhtmltopdf)

Comment: @M.Twarog no, it is not duplicate, look closer

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem through merging **separated** pdf files into one using **PdfSharp**, instead of passing concatenated content to `wkhtmltopdf` as one. It lasts a little bit longer, but at least it works. Except of `PdfSharp` library (if you use MVC as me, then `PdfSharp.Core` to exclude version warnings), probably you would need to install `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` to exclude encoding error that `PdfSharp` may cause. My method does not use temp files and works only with bytes, at the end it sends created pdf to a browser.

```
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;

public IActionResult createPdf()
{
    string html = "";
    byte[] pdf = null;

    using(PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            html = "html content";

            Process p;
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

            psi.FileName = "...\\wkhtmltopdf.exe";
            psi.WorkingDirectory = "...\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin";

            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
            psi.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            psi.Arguments = "-O landscape --footer-left qwe --footer-center [page]/[topage] --footer-right --footer-font-size 9 --no-stop-slow-scripts --zoom 0.8 --dpi 300 - - ";

            p = Process.Start(psi);

            using(StreamWriter stdin = new StreamWriter(p.StandardInput.BaseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                stdin.AutoFlush = true;
                stdin.Write(html);
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
            byte[] currentPdf = null;
            using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    int read = p.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); 

                    if(read <= 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }       
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                 }
                 currentPdf = ms.ToArray();
             }

             p.StandardOutput.Close();
             p.WaitForExit(10000);
             p.Close();     

             MemoryStream currentPDF = new MemoryStream(currentPdf);

             // Merge separated pdfs into one
// Solves encoding errors   
System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

             using(PdfDocument pdfDoc = PdfReader.Open(currentPDF, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
             {
                 for(int j = 0; j < pdfDoc.PageCount; j++)
                 {
                     doc.AddPage(pdfDoc.Pages[j]);
                 }
             }

             currentPDF.Close();
        }

        // Get merged pdfs as bytes
        MemoryStream rms = new MemoryStream();
        doc.Save(rms, false);
        pdf = rms.ToArray();
        rms.Close();
    }

    MemoryStream PDF = new MemoryStream(pdf);

    // Return PDF to browser
    return new FileStreamResult(PDF, "application/x-msdownload")
    {
        FileDownloadName = "mergedPdfs.pdf"
    }; 
}
```